# ArrayList of Pracelable object causing exception

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm getting an exception when I pass an arraylist of a Parcelable object to GCM service.
Help will be greatly appreciated.

This is not the case of some other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473348/class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-android-intent-parcelable)) where they had an ArrayList inside a parcelable object. I have an ArrayList of a parcelable object

I have the following Parcelable class:

```
public class PreferencesLeg implements Parcelable {

public int index;
public int pref1;
public int pref2;

public PreferencesLeg(int index, int pref1, int pref2) {
    this.index = index;
    this.pref1 = pref1;
    this.pref2 = pref2;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.index);
    dest.writeInt(this.pref1);
    dest.writeInt(this.pref2);
}

protected PreferencesLeg(Parcel in) {
    this.index = in.readInt();
    this.pref1 = in.readInt();
    this.pref2 = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<PreferencesLeg> CREATOR = new Creator<PreferencesLeg>() {
    public PreferencesLeg createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new PreferencesLeg(source);
    }

    public PreferencesLeg[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PreferencesLeg[size];
    }
};
}
```

I am using this class as follows:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
ArrayList<PreferencesLeg> preferencesLegs = new ArrayList<>();
for (Leg leg : legList.legs) {

    PreferencesLeg preferencesLeg = new PreferencesLeg(leg.index, leg.pref1,
            leg.pref2);
    preferencesLegs.add(preferencesLeg);
}
extras.putParcelableArrayList(PREFERENCES_LEGS, preferencesLegs);


OneoffTask oneoffTask = new OneoffTask.Builder()
        .setService(UpdatePreferencesService.class)
        .setTag(unique_id)
        .setExtras(extras)
        .setExecutionWindow(0.0F, 10.0F)
        .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
        .setUpdateCurrent(true)
        .build();

GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this).schedule(oneoffTask);

...

public class UpdatePreferencesService extends GcmTaskService {
    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {

        String id = taskParams.getTag();
        Bundle extras = taskParams.getExtras();

        ArrayList<PreferencesLeg> preferencesLegs = extras.getParcelableArrayList(PREFERENCES_LEGS);


...
```

and I get an exception when I try to run the task:

```
10-27 16:26:12.158  10934-10934/com.google.process.gapps E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: com.models.PreferencesLeg
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.models.PreferencesLeg
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:101)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:81)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.h.a(SourceFile:55)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.i.handleMessage(SourceFile:170)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.models.PreferencesLeg" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:101)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:81)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.h.a(SourceFile:55)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.i.handleMessage(SourceFile:170)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com...models.PreferencesLeg
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 23 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
10-27 16:26:12.158  10934-10934/com.google.process.gapps D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-27 16:26:12.158  10934-10934/com.google.process.gapps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.process.gapps, PID: 10934
    android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.models.PreferencesLeg
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:101)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.a.<init>(SourceFile:81)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.h.a(SourceFile:55)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.nts.i.handleMessage(SourceFile:170)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class not found when Unmarshalling Android Intent Parcelable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473348/class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-android-intent-parcelable)

Comment: I son't think it's the same. They had an ArrayList inside a parcelable object. I have an ArrayList of a parcelable object

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set ClassLoader directly.

```
extras.setClassLoader(PreferencesLeg.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, that didn't solve it, but I did learn something new