# Passing Object in Bundle - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem passing a custom class to another activity resulting in a Activity Manager crash. I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable/Parcelable {
    public final String a;
    public final Long b;
    public final Boolean c;
}


Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class);
Bundle parameter = new Bundle();
parameter.putParcelable(TargetActivity.DATA_KEY, instance_of_my_class);
startActivity(intent, parameter);
```

I have tried both `Serializable` as well as `Parcelable` and both ways fail with the same problem: `ClassNotFoundException`.

There are some older discussions about this where `setClassLoader` and `setExtrasClassLoader` are recommended, unfortunately it does not work. For example I have tried `parameter.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());` the result was the same.

Anyone knows the solution? Is it possible that a third party library has an influence on this? (I have EventBus in the project)

The stack trace in the Parcelable case looks like this:

```
08-23 14:40:37.086 1487-1783/system_process E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.example.MyClass
                                                  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyClass
                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityOptions.<init>(ActivityOptions.java:570)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.<init>(ActivityRecord.java:417)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1482)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:951)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3369)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3356)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:139)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2208)
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyClass" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
                                                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281) 
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245) 
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152) 
                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485) 
                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918) 
                                                      at android.app.ActivityOptions.<init>(ActivityOptions.java:570) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.<init>(ActivityRecord.java:417) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1482) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:951) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3369) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3356) 
                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:139) 
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2208) 
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyClass
                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                            ... 19 more
                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: What exactly is the stacktrace? Which class is not found? And please show the full class definition because you can't just implement Parcelable and have it work

Comment: So where is the constructor that takes PARCEL and the CREATOR?

Comment: please add full code.

Comment: Of case it has the necessary methods implemented and a CREATOR constructor. Just wanted to summarize on the essantials.
The stack trace varies depending on if I go the Serializable or the Parcelable way but the meaning is the same. It can't find my class.

Comment: Random guess. Is the class package name matching your applicationId?

Comment: No, the class which is not found is a bit deeper in the package structure so the applicationId is only the prefix of its package name.

Comment: might be connected with this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473348/class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-android-intent-parcelable

Comment: Please show the code where you are putting the custom class instances into the `Intent` and what you are doing with this `Intent`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshalling errors in Android app with custom parcelable classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997550/unmarshalling-errors-in-android-app-with-custom-parcelable-classes)

Comment: possible duplitcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat

Answer (score 0):

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a non-null static field called CREATOR of a type that implements the Parcelable.Creator interface.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

To make that in a easy way try to find plugins which will handle parcelable creation.
Example: 
https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin